# Two CSS Class have different border-color value and only one working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the border color of a textarea. I have used jQuery for doing so. Previously, I was using `.css("border-color","rgb(250,0,0)")`, and it was working fine. Now I am told not to use CSS in Javascript and use Class.

So I created one class named:

```
.redBorderColor{
    border-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

and in jQuery I used:

```
.addClass("redBorderColor")
```

When I checked it in browser, then I find class name is there in textarea's class attribute, but border color does not change. I have seen in firebug following class, from Pure CSS which was already implemented in project:

```
.pure-form select, .pure-form textarea {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #ddd inset;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
}
```

Question is that, I want my new style class to be implemented and previous one should be not considered or ignored. As of now, my style is cut off by firebug

Comment: Your CSS class is `redBorderColor` but you are adding `redBorderClass`, is that a typo?

Comment: .addClass("redBorder**Color**")

Comment: If you use a class instead of inline, the new selector has to be at least as specific as the existing one, and follow it in the CSS if equivalent, in order to replace it. What is the initial styling selector CSS and where is it? ... but I see now you just had a typo by the look of it :)

Comment: @Sourabh- Sorry it was typo in question, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note the typo; `redBorderClass` in your JS code should be `redBorderColor`.

That said, you also need to make the `redBorderColor` CSS class more specific so that it over-rules the other CSS styling. You can use either `!important`:

```
.redBorderColor {
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Or you can make the selector more specific:

```
.pure-form textarea.redBorderColor {
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Note that the latter is better practice.

Comment: It was typo in question. Sorry for that. I have corrected.

Thanks. It worked for me. Let me analyze if it is not impacted somewhere else, then i will mark it an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
.redBorderColor
```

while you are adding:

```
redBorderClass
```

---

Issue seems to me is a simple typo. You have defined your css selector as `.redBorderColor`, here you can see *Color*.

On the otherside when you are adding the class with js/jquery you have used `redBorderClass` not `redBorderColor`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna ignore or not considered the previous class, then remove the current class and add your class.

```
.removeClass('pure-form').addClass("redBorderColor");
```

Then, put this into your class to keep the other configuration.

```
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #ddd inset;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
```

Comment: Unusual to remove the current one, rather than just overwrite the styles. That would then require all other styles be duplicated from `pure-form`